# How to load DLL using C#?

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I have a small DLL that has 3 functions : Init, Load and run.
I'm new with c# so as I read the questions here, I've opened a console project and wanted to load the DLL and use it's functions.
unfortunately - it didn't work. can anyone advise what went wrong?

This is the error I get:

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'Init' in DLL 
'....path to my DLL....'.
```

this is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
    {

       [DllImport("C:\\Desktop\\DLLTest.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool Init();

        [DllImport("C:\\Desktop\\DLLTest.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
         public static extern bool Load(string file);


         [DllImport("C:\\Desktop\\DLLTest.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool Play();



        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("got till here!!!");

            Init();

            Load("C:\\Desktop\\the_thing_about_dogs_480x270.mp4");
            Play();

        }
    }
```

}

The only thing I can suspect is maybe the fact that I'm not creating an instance?
besides that, no clue :(

*** editing : ***
this is the DLL :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DLLTest
{
    public class DLLTestApi
    {
    myInfo localPlay;

    public bool Init()
    {
        localPlay =  new myInfo();

        return true;

    }


    public bool Load(string file)
    {
        localPlay.Load(file);
        return true;
    }
    public bool Play()
    {
        localPlay.StartNewThread();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop()
    {
        localPlay.DxStopWMp();
        return true;

    }
    public bool Pause()
    {
        localPlay.DxPause();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Resume()
    {
        localPlay.DxResume();
        return true;
    }
    public bool Close()
    {
        localPlay.DxClose();
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it your DLL? Have you exported the `Init` function properly?

Comment: Is `DLLTest.dll` a .Net assembly?

Comment: What kind of DLL? COM? Native? .Net?

Comment: It looks like the runtime finds `DLLTest.dll` just fine.  The error seems to be the export of the `Init` function.  Can you post the native declarations of these functions?  That is likely where the error is

Comment: Sorry for the missing information. I've edited it - added the DLL. It's written in c# as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you clearly what the problem is. Your DLL does not export a function named `Init`. Possible reasons for this include:

1. The DLL is not an unmanaged DLL.
2. The DLL simply does not export a function of that name.
3. The DLL exports that function, but the name is decorated or mangled.

Probably the easiest way to diagnose the fault is to use a tool like Dependency Walker to inspect the DLL's exports.

**Update**

From the edit to the question, it is clear that item 1 is the reason. Your DLL is a managed DLL and it is incorrect to attempt to access it using p/invoke. Simply add it as a reference to your console application project.

Comment: Yes, item 1 is the explanation.

Comment: David is correct, managed dll do not export symbols in the same way unmanaged do. Reference the dll in your project and use it like you would any other managed assembly.

Answer (score 0):

To load a dll dynamically, not sure if it applies to a managed dll, use Assembly.LoadFrom() from System.Reflection;

To create an instance use Activator.CreateInstance() from System.Activator;